# Complexity of multiplying two polynomials with different degree

Tags: complexity-theory

I am aware that we can use the Fast Fourier Transform to multiply two polynomials of degree n in O(n log n) time. This is a big savings from the brute force approach in O(n^2) time. Is it possible to generalize this result to two polynomials of different degree?

Clearly, it can be done in O(n log n) where n is the larger number, but I'm looking for an answer that depends on both n and m.

Comment: This probably belongs on [CS Theory Stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), or possibly on one of the math stackexchange sites.

Comment: I would add that your proposed result is almost certainly possible, because multiplying a degree `n` polynomial and a degree `1` polynomial is trivially `O(n)` even without transforming to a complex exponential basis.